# How to verify that the timestamp send is in UTC in mongoose/Hapijs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

I'm building an application in node.js using Hapi and database in Mongodb using Mongoose. I have the following message schema:

```
var schema = {
    from : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId,
        ref : 'User'
    },
    content : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    group : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Group'
    },
    created : {
        type : Number,
        default : Date.now()
    }
};
```

I want the `created` field in the schema to be a timestamp and always be in UTC. For this my client always converts its current timestamp into its UTC timestamp and then sends to the server. However, I can't find a possible way on the server to verify whether the timestamp provided has been converted into UTC or not. Is there any way I could impose that validation in Hapi/Mongoose?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

1. Changed the type of `created` field to be `Number` since I want to store the `timestamp` and not the date string.

Comment: I would hazard to say that it depends on how your dates are being submitted from the client. Chances are ( and good practice ) that it's a "string". So you could just do: `"2015-06-14T06:26:30.510Z".substr(-1) == "Z"` Since "Z" will be the last character if that string was in UTC format. Also note that validation hooks in mongoose fire "after" any "type" conversions made by the schema. So any valid date string is going to be converted once you commit the write operation, regardless of whether it was UTC or not.

Comment: what if I change the type of 'created' field to be just a Number and then store it as sent from the client(as a timestamp)? I'm sorry I should have stated that earlier, I now realize that storing field as type 'Date' will always convert it to be a date string instead of a 'timestamp' number which is exactly what I want. I'll update the 'created' type in the question in a min.

Comment: Well firstly I'd advise on keeping the "date" type as MongoDB can work with dates quite nicely and natively, and there are even a few tricks to work that that type as a "timestamp" ( which Is basically the internal storage anyway) so there are no real advantages and just disadvantages to changing that. Secondly, if its a "numeric" format as a timestamp then it will be UTC anyhow, since Unix timestamps to not record "timezone" information.

Answer (score 2):

Hapi allows you to have a `validate` property on each route. Under the hood this uses Joi to validate the schema provided in this property to the payload, parameters, query string and headers: [Route Configuration](http://hapijs.com/api#route-configuration)

Using this you can validate your `created` field to a particular date format: [date.format()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#dateformatformat)

For example this will validate it to ISO 8601 format:

```
    validate: {
        payload: {
            created: Joi.date().iso();
        }
    }
```